# How to multiply xml in bash

Tags: xml, bash, xpath

How do i multiply the following line by let's say 3?

```
$(xmllint --xpath '/rates/currency['code="\"$code1\""']/rate/text()' rates.xml)
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that that command outputs an integer:

```
echo $(( 3 * $(xmllint --xpath '/rates/currency['code="\"$code1\""']/rate/text()' rates.xml) ))
```

If it's not an integer, but a fractional number you can't do it in pure bash (bash only supports integer math), but you could still use bc:

```
{
  printf '3 *'
  xmllint --xpath '/rates/currency['code="\"$code1\""']/rate/text()' rates.xml
} | bc
```

Comment: Command outputs floating number, 2.55 for example. How do i go about it?

Answer (score 2):

XPath can handle arithmetics.

```
xmllint --xpath '3 * /rates/currency['code="\"$code1\""']/rate'
```

Comment: *facepalm* I should've known this.

Comment: This works, thanks. But how do i multiply it by variable?

    xmllint --xpath '$x * /rates/currency['code="\"$code1\""']/rate'

This doesnt work

Comment: `xmllint --xpath $x' * /rates/currency['code="\"$code1\""']/rate'`

Comment: @user2939526: Shell does not interpolate variables in single quotes. It does in double quotes or outside quotes.